# java eclipse red exclamation mark

Tags: java, eclipse

I have just got a new computer and installed Eclipse Indigo and all of the plugins that I use. But when I open my workspace from my old computer some projects have an exclamation mark.
What does a red exclamation mark mean on a project folder?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The red exclamation mark usually means there is a problem with the Build Path. 
Do you see any alerts in the "Problem" View?

Comment: I see that the project is missing a mysql connector.. Thanx :)

Answer (score 30):

It means that there is an error on that project..
You can look at all the errors in the Problems tab. press ALT SHIFT Q followed by X  to 
show this tab.

Answer (score 7):

It means that there are two things happened.........

1. What ever jar file or project setup jar file for your application
   are not located at that point where it was earlier in your computer.
   So that First you have to setup your project with all the jar files
   and refresh it.
2. Check syntax in your project might be some mistake in that.

Answer (score 6):

The red exclamation mark in eclipse is because of the problem/issue with the build path.

To find the specific issue look at the problems tab of the eclipse.

Window -> Show View -> Problems (or) <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>,<kbd>X</kbd>

[image: problems tab of eclipse]

Answer (score 5):

If you didn't find any error on the project files, usually it means your build path has some issue. First Check your jar file and jar file locations.

On eclispe, right click on your project, Go to build path and go to Configure build path. Check any errors under libraries. Configure it correctly and refresh the project.

Answer (score 2):

It appears mostly because of "build path" only. But just in case you are working on a MAVEN project, here is the solution.

**Solution**

**Step 1**. Expand your project in Eclipse > Right click on "JRE System Library" > "Build Path" > "Remove From Build path"

**Step 2**. Expand your project in Eclipse > Right click on "Maven Dependencies" > "Build Path" > "Remove From Build path"

**Step 3**. Reach out to your local repository and follow below path "C:\Users\userName\.m2\repository" and delete everything inside repository folder

**Step 4**. Refresh your project in Eclipse

**Step 5**. Right Click on your project > "Maven" > "Update Project"

**Step 6**. Just refresh your project and now we are Ready to GO..

Answer (score 1):

In my case show hidden files was enabled and i had added hidden jar file extensions along with the original jars. Adding only the jar files except the hidden files solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

It can appear when any other file other than .jar is added in the jar library. To fix this, remove the file and clean the project.

Answer (score 1):

If it is maven project and your project view having no error. Then try the following steps

Right click the project ---> maven --> update maven

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

What the error means is that the Java (JDK) version installed needs an update, as the older version could not be read. To rectify the issue, uninstall your Java (JDK) and install the latest version. Restart eclipse and the would be seen resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This may help in case your build path is correct and you have put the right signature and access specifier for main, so maybe used as a hook to try before you make any modifications to your build path.

Just go to your problems bar and delete the problem given for the project, clean the project and build it. It should solve the problem, if these steps cause the red exclamation to go away.